# Proving that the digamma newton series converges

Tags: calculus

The digamma function has the following series representation:

$$\psi(x+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x!}{\left(x-n\right)!n!n}$$

How would you prove that the above series converges? I tried using the alternating series test however it does not work in this case as the function is not monotonic decreasing. My second idea was to use asymptotics for the binomial coefficient, however I was unable to make this work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the reflection formula
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}
$$
with $z=x-n+1$ (assuming that $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$) we get
$$
\Gamma(x-n+1)\Gamma(n-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi (x-n+1))}.
$$
Therefore, the absolute values of the coefficients in the series are
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n!n\Gamma(x-n+1)}\right|\leq \frac{|\Gamma(n-x)|}{\pi n!n}\sim\frac 1{\pi n^{x+2}}.
$$
In the last step we use the following consequence of Stirling's approximation:
$$
\Gamma(z+a)\sim z^a\Gamma(z),\qquad z\to+\infty,\ a\in \mathbb C.
$$
Hence the series converges whenever $x>-1$.

Answer (score 0):

For any fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\left| {\dfrac{{\dfrac{1}{{(x - n - 1)!(n + 1)!(n + 1)}}}}{{\dfrac{1}{{(x - n)!n!n}}}}} \right| = \left| {\frac{{(x - n)n}}{{(n + 1)^2 }}} \right| = 1 - \frac{{x + 2}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right),
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. Thus, by the [Gauss test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html), the series converges absolutely iff $x>-1$.