# Convergence of infinite asymptotic series

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have an infinite series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$$
and that $a_n\sim b_n$. If the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$$
converges can we also conclude that the series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges?

The motivation behind this question is the answer by Giulio on this post [Proving that the digamma newton series converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571917/proving-that-the-digamma-newton-series-converges). Initially I thought it was possible but then I realized that $a_n$ may be asymptotic to $b_n$ from above, in which case the $a_n$ sum could diverge whilst the $b_n$ sum converges. So is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: for nonnegative numbers yes (because convergence means series bounded and that is obvious even if $c a_n \le b_n \le Ca_n, c,C>0$ so even if $a_n,b_n$ are of same size but not necessarily asymptotic , but otherwise no as something like $(-1)^n/n+1/(n\log n), (-1)^n/n$ shows

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for your answer! Really appreciate it. So just to be really clear (sorry, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this) if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|b_{n}\right|$ converges and $|b_n| \sim |a_n|$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right|$ converges?

Comment: it is enough to have $C >0$ st $|a_n| \le C|b_n|$ for this implication since then $\sum_{n \le N} |a_n| \le C \sum_{n \le N} |b_n| \le CM$ where $M=\sum |b_n| < \infty$; obviously $|a_n|/|b_n| \to 1$ implies the existence of such a $C$